# Reference on Doob's h-transform

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, stochastic-processes, potential-theory

I am searching for a reference about conditioning a Markov process in the sense of Doob, i.e. using h-transforms. My particular concern is to condition a discrete-time Markov Process on a possibly null-measure event, and I would need results such as conditions for uniqueness of extremal harmonic functions , maybe results related to Green's functions...

I found :

- The (big) book of Doob, *Classical potential theory and its probabilistic counterpart* which is very general and would need a substantial investment to be understood.
- The book of Rogers and Williams *Diffusions, Markov processes and martingales*, which is not very detailed, and mainly deals with the continuous time case.
- Draft notes of A Bloemendal on the net http://www.math.harvard.edu/~alexb/rm/Doob.pdf
- Some explanations in an article of O'Connel *Conditioned random walks and RSK correspondence* http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~masgas/pubs/noc03a.pdf

Anyone would have an other idea ?

Comment: One alternative reference : Denumerable markov chains, by Wolfgang Woess, 2009, if one is interested in homogeneous Markov chains.

Comment: And better, the first volume of the book of Rogers and Williams, "Diffusions, Markov processes and martingales" actually summarizes Doob(and Martin, Hunt)'s theory. A smaller part of the second volume treats the case of h-transforms in the continuous case.

Comment: In this brand new paper http://arxiv.org/pdf/1405.5157v1.pdf pag 19 they revise the historical definition of Doob's transform. Did you find other references? I'm also looking for them!

Answer (score 3):

It's not a great answer (I've not enough reputation to comment) but it explains the concept without much mathematical garnish:

http://linbaba.wordpress.com/2010/06/02/doob-h-transforms/

A book (page 242) Markov chains and mixing times - David A. Levin, Yuval Peres, Elizabeth L. Wilmer